# Is there a way to apply multiple helpers to a template in Handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js

I have two Handlebars helpers which I use.

First is `timeboundset` which takes an array and a datefield and only selects and applies those elements which fall after that datefield.

Second is `sortedset` which sorts the array first and then uses its elements.

Is there a way I can use both the helpers on the array in html itself and not doing any workaround in Javascript?

Comment: In my opinion, if needed, array should be sorted before being passed as parameter. That's not really the role of a template to manage data. Handlebars helpers are more formatting functions than data managers.

Comment: I suppose you could write another helper that lets you chain helper calls but you're probably better off following Simon Boudrias's advice. You can easily make your helper functions available outside the templates you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no plans to support that functionality.

https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/304

Although, there's an implementation you could try out if you really want it.

Answer (score 26):

[amwmedia commented on GitHub on Oct 7, 2014](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/304#issuecomment-58201556) that "this appears to have native support using something like:"

```
{{ helper1 (helper2 text) }}
```

It does indeed appear to work natively, without the need to register a helper. Note that the helper *inside* the `()` braces is executed first, the helper outside last:

```
{{ executesLast (executesFirst text) }}
```

Comment: but this appears to break if i am passing arguments: `{{ executesLast (arg executesFirst text) }}` while parser would complain adding a comma! any thoughts?

Comment: Does it still complain in 2019?